# Bind list of list in JSF

Tags: jsf, datatable, nested-lists

This is my class as `model` which have 2 lists as key value pairs. One sample consists of many key value pairs. And I want to iterate this sample's list on view of the same bean class.

```
    public class Sample {

        List<String> sampleKey;
        List<String> sampleValue;
        boolean editable;

        public Sample(List<String> sampleKey, List<String> sampleValue) {
            this.sampleKey = sampleKey;
            this.sampleValue = sampleValue;
        }

        public boolean isEditable() {
            return editable;
        }

        public void setEditable(boolean editable) {
            this.editable = editable;
        }

        public List<String> getsampleKey() {
            return sampleKey;
        }

        public void setsampleKey(List<String> sampleKey) {
            this.sampleKey = sampleKey;
        }

        public List<String> getsampleValue() {
            return sampleValue;
        }

        public void setsampleValuee(List<String> sampleValue) {
            this.sampleValue = sampleValue;
        }
    }
    public ArrayList<Sample> sampleList;
        Sample sam = null;
        sampleList = new ArrayList<Sample>();
        List<Map.Entry<String, List<String>>> entryList = new ArrayList<>(records.entrySet());
        for (int j = 0; j < maxSamples; j++) {
            ArrayList<String> sampleKey = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<String> sampleValue = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 7; i < records.size(); i++) {

                List<String> sample = entryList.get(i).getValue();
                if (!sample.isEmpty()) {
                    sampleKey.add(keyList.get(i));
                    if (!sample.get(j).isEmpty()) {
                        sampleValue.add(sample.get(j));
                    }
                }
            }
             sam = new Sample(sampleKey, sampleValue);
             sampleList.add(sam);
        }
```

Now here is my view of same bean class:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{dataEntryFormController.sampleList}"
    var="key" varStatus="recordMetadata">
    <h:dataTable
        value="#{dataEntryFormController.sampleList[recordMetadata.index]}"
        var="o" binding="#{table}">
        <h:column>
            <h:inputText value="#{o.sampleKey[table.rowIndex]}" size="10" rendered="#{o.editable}" />
            <h:outputText value="#{o.sampleKey[table.rowIndex]}" rendered="#{not o.editable}" />
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <h:inputText value="#{o.sampleValue[table.rowIndex]}" size="20"rendered="#{o.editable}" />
            <h:outputText value="#{o.sampleValue[table.rowIndex]}" rendered="#{not o.editable}" />
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
</ui:repeat>
```

In my JSF page, I want to bind that list of list to view for iterating over a number of samples and each sample may have many key value pairs. With the above code, I can only print 1 key value pair at a time.

I am having issue in binding.

Comment: why do you need binding? The datatable has a rowIndexVar that you can use for the index

Comment: I just want to print these key value pairs in a row fashion.  in sampleList maybe a couple of samples are there but inside a sample, there are multiple key value pairs maybe more than 30. I am having an issue to print that in an iterative way.